# Retrieve the current screen refresh rate on macOS Monterey with ProMotion

Tags: swift, macos, apple-m1

Is it possible to retrieve the *current* accurate screen refresh rate for M1 Max and Pro Macs equipped with ProMotion?
As far as I was able to understand it works differently than other Mac's screens (?), and I was wondering if it was possible to retrieve the info from somewhere (possibly at regular intervals...? but that'll be a question for later).

Thanks!